# Keeping a Base Form Hidden

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Fairly simple, I think. I have a base form with a title. All of my forms have to inherit this. They are! How do I keep this base form invisible at all times, though, while still launching a login screen at start up?

Or, to put another way, the program is going to flow like this:

Base form (invisible, for visual inheritance only)
to
Login
to
Search
to
Shopping Cart

Hope this is clear.

Comment: If that base form is used for inheritance only, then there is no reason to ever create an instance of it in the first place, so why care if it's visible or not? You'll only create and show derived forms.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow you. For what it's worth, the assignment is specifically asking me to make a base form for that inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it now.

When you're using inheritance, you create instances of the *derived* classes, but not from the base one, that's why you should not worry about the base form ever appearing as it never exists on its own.

Suppose for example that you have this (I'll use C# as you don't have specified a language, but it's the same in anything else)

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    // Here you define the base properties/methods/events, together with the controls you want everywhere in the designer
}

public class Form1 : BaseForm    // Note that it derives from BaseForm, NOT Form
{
    // Properties/methods/events specific to Form1, and designer with added things only for it
}

// Same for another form
public class Form2 : BaseForm
{
    // Properties/methods/events specific to Form2, and designer with added things only for it
}
```

Is that your scenario like this isn't it? Well, now, when you're going to use both forms, you need at some point to create them in code, more or less it will be this:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
// Set properties to initial values and so on
form1.Show();

Form2 form2 = new Form2();
// Set properties to initial values and so on
form2.Show();
```

So, this piece of code will display both forms on the screen. But it's those 2 forms only, nothing more. At NO point you ever write `new BaseForm()`, that's why it will never appear on its own. Code on it will run, but only as part of the other derived forms.